# Is the word in this sentence, Russian, capitalized or lowercase?

Tags: proper-nouns, capitalization, names

I want to write:

> In Russian/russian, this is a common technique....

Which letter I should use?

Answer (score 3):

It's not an adjective here, it's a noun, and it should be capitalized. Names of languages are treated like proper nouns in English.

Comment: Even if I add the word "language"?     In russian language...

Comment: "Russian language" would be a compound noun and would still be capitalized. Even when used alone as a genuine adjective, as in "I am reading a Russian book," the word is _still_ [usually (almost always)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capitalization#Adjectives) capitalized because it derives from a proper noun.